# Prove there are infinitely many fields in which the polynomial is reducable

Tags: polynomials, factoring

Polynomial: $$ t^7+t^2+1$$

I have the solution, but I don't understand the thinking behind it. How are they coming up with the factorization, and specific values of $t$ (shown in solution).

The solution says: Note that in complex field for $t=e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}, t^7=t$. That means that the polynomial is divisible by $t+t^2+1$ and 
$$ t^7+t^2+1=(t+t^2+1)(t^5-t^4+t^2-t+1)$$
This factorization obviously holds for any polynomials considered under any finite field $(\{0, 1, ..., p-1\}, +, \cdot)$ where $p$ is prime, and $-1=p-1$. Obviously this factorization holds for any field.

Could anyone explain it to me in more details?

Comment: You never wrote what the problem is.

Comment: You have in hand a proof that $t^7+t^2+1$ factors over $\Bbb Z$, so that the polynomial is reducible over all fields. But your title merely asks to show that there are infinitely many fields over which it is reducible. That is an immensely weaker statement than what you have a proof of.

Comment: Are you sure you're expected to be able to discover the root for yourself? Verifying the root once its known is much easier, and may be all that is expected of you for this example. (and the author may well have come up with the problem by starting with the choice of root and then finding a polynomial for which it is a root)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are saying that you do not understand the solution you were given.

Take a cube root of one,
$$ \omega = - \frac{1}{2} + i \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}=e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}.  $$
Then

$$  (x - \omega)(x - \omega^2) =  x^2 + x + 1 $$

Both $\omega$ and $\omega^2$ are roots of your polynomial, since
$$ 7 \equiv 1 \pmod 3.  $$ The polynomials over a field form a Euclidean ring, the two linear factors have gcd 1, therefore your polynomial is divisible by $x^2 + x + 1.$

Suppose the problem were
$$ \color{blue}{ g(x) = x^{2017} + x^{1066} + x^{153} + x^{19} + 1.} $$
Then the exponents would be
$$ 2, 1, 3, 4, 0 \pmod 5.  $$
As a result, we take a non-real fifth root of $1,$
$$ \omega =e^{i\frac{2\pi}{5}}.  $$
Since 
$$ \omega^5 = 1, $$ we get
$$ g(\omega) = \omega^2 + \omega +  \omega^3 + \omega^4 + 1. $$
However, since $x^5 - 1 = (x-1)(x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)$ and $\omega \neq 1,$ we find
$$  \omega^4 + \omega^3 +  \omega^2 + \omega + 1 = 0,  $$
so
$$ g( \omega) = 0,  $$
$$ g( \omega^2) = 0,  $$
$$ g( \omega^3) = 0,  $$
$$ g( \omega^4) = 0.  $$ 
Therefore
$$  (x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1) \; | \; g(x) = x^{2017} + x^{1066} + x^{153} + x^{19} + 1.   $$

Comment: how do you come up with $\omega$? Is it arbitrary?

Comment: @StefanStipanovic I added another example to show how $\omega$ is chosen. You really should go through the details, fill in any gaps I did not explain, yourself.

Answer (score 1):

$t^2+t+1$ divides $t^7+t^2+1$, hence $t^7+t^2+1$ cannot be an irreducible polynomial.

In order to check that $t^2+t+1$ is actually a divisor of $t^7+t^2+1$, it is enough to check that $t^7+t^2+1$ vanishes at the roots of $t^2+t+1$, that are the primitive third roots of unity since $t^2+t+1=\frac{t^3-1}{t-1}=\Phi_3(t)$. But is $\omega$ is a primitive third root of unity, $\omega^7=\omega^1$, so $t^7+t^2+1$ evaluated at $t=\omega$ equals $\omega^7+\omega^2+1 = 1+\omega+\omega^2 = 0.$ At last, the identity

$$t^7+t^2+1 = (t^2+t+1)(t^5-t^4+t^2-t+1) $$
is straightforward to check.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to understand how the factor $t^2+t+1$ is deduced **(say directly if $t=e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}$ then $t^7=t$  is having too much lucidity)**. The writer wants to reduce the degree and the ideal reduction he thought is the second degree. Then he saw that $$t^7=t\iff t^7-t=t(t^3-1)(t^3+1)=0$$ hence the non real root of $1$ might agree. This lead him to the factor $t^2+t+1=\frac{t^3-1}{t-1}$ wich  besides being good it gives also the other factor after division.